# Check Length of each cell in specific column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an excel spreadsheet that is giving me an error for a specific column. It's a truncate error so i am needing to check each cell in column O for length >= 8000. The datatype is varchar(max) so by checking this i can see which row is being rejected. This error occurred when trying to import the data into SQL server. I need to find which row is causing the error and fix it so i can import the data. The error actually states its either a truncate exception or a invalid character so this method will at least solve one of the questions. The top row is the column names if that matters. I believe i need something like this LEN(Column O) >= 8000 but im not very excel savy so hopefully i can find help here :)

Comment: what do you mean by `invalid character`? perhaps this part may be solved as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039385/truncation-errors-importing-to-sql-server-2005-from-excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new column in the raw data. Call it "Greater than 8000"
Put a formula in the next cell down (row 2 I assume). Then put this formula in there:

`=IF(LEN(O2)>8000,"YES","NO")`

copy and paste the formula to the last cell row.

Then apply a filter to the data (click on a1, then click Home-->Sort & Filter --> Filter). Then go to the new column "Greater than 8000" and filter for "YES".

Comment: This worked on the first try! Awesome :) Nothing was greater than 8000 so now i have to figure out what else could be wrong :( haha Thanks!

Comment: @user1732364 glad it worked! that's unfortunate that you have to keep digging. post a new question on the SQL import error you're getting. i'm sure someone can help

Answer (score 0):

LEN(InsertYourCellHere) will indeed give you the lenght of text inside the cell. What you can do is create a new rule in Conditional Formatting menu => Use a formula to determine which cells to format. There you will enter the LEN() formula.